# bach scripts run by crontab as root

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, cron, centos7

I run a crontab script to check if ffmpeg is running.
I want the scripts to inform me if ffmpeg is not running.
When I run the scripts as root on the command line all is OK
But when they run called from crontab they never show the error.
They always show that ffmpeg is running inspite of the fact that sometimes ffmpeg has crashed.

I have given my crontab file and the scripts below.

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
57 4 * * * pkill -f /usr/bin/python2.7
57 4 * * * pkill -f /bin/ffmpeg
2 5 * * * /opt/dls/cron.sh (restarting the process above.)
*/5 * * * * /root/test-ffmpeg.sh  testing if ffmpeg is running
*/5 * * * * /root/test.sh         testing if ffmpeg is running
*/5 * * * * /root/test2.sh        testing if ffmpeg is running
```

scripts: test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#check if ffmpeg is running
if pgrep ffmpeg >/dev/null 2>&1
if ps cax | rev | cut -f1 -d' ' | rev |grep ffmpeg >/dev/null 2>&1
then
echo "My Process is running."
else
echo "Hello" | mutt -s "fffmpeg is not working" abc@gmail.com
fi
```

script test-ffmpeg.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#check if ffmpeg is running
if pgrep ffmpeg >/dev/null 2>&1
then
echo "Process is running."
else
echo "Hello" | mutt -s "ffmpeg is not working" abc@gmail.com
fi
```

script: test2.sh

```
line=$(ps aux | grep ffmpeg)
if [ -z "$line" ]
then
echo "Hello" | mutt -s "fffmpeg is not working" abc@gmail.com    
else
echo $line > /dev/null
echo "Running"
fi
```

Comment: Change `(ps aux | grep ffmpeg)` to `(ps aux | grep ffmpeg | grep -v grep)`. Otherwise `ps` is matching the `grep ffmpeg` line.

Comment: Why does `test.sh` have two `if` lines in a row?

Comment: As a rule -- don't use `ps | grep` to check if a process is already running. Use advisory locks, as with `flock` -- or, better, a real process supervision system (on CentOS 7, that would be systemd).

Comment: ...if you have systemd working, then it's just `if systemctl is-active ffmpeg.service`, assuming you created a `ffmpeg.service` that runs your script.

Comment: (and that won't false-positive if you don't have `ffmpeg` itself running but do have `vim test-ffmpeg.sh`).

Comment: Greetings, Thank you for the comment Barmar,
 
Change (ps aux | grep ffmpeg) to (ps aux | grep ffmpeg | grep -v grep).        Otherwise ps is matching the grep ffmpeg line. – Barmar This settled my problem and this subject is closed